# Multiple binders not working with Spring-Cloud-Stream and Spring-Kubernetes on Kubernetes

Tags: java, azureservicebus, spring-cloud-stream, servicebus, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I have Spring-Cloud-Stream Azure Service-Bus Binder application with uses multiple binders:

```yaml
spring:
  application:
    name: my-application
  cloud:
    azure:
      servicebus:
        connection-string: CON_STRING_1
    stream:
      binders:
        second-binder:
          type: servicebus-queue
          default-candidate: false
          environment:
            spring:
              cloud:
                azure:
                  servicebus:
                    connection-string: CON_STRING_2
      bindings:
        first-destination:
          destination: first-binder-queue
        second-destination:
          destination: second-binder-queue
          binder: second-binder
      function:
        definition: my-function
```

When I am running the application locally it connects to both binders successfully.

```
...
Created queue client to connection string 'Endpoint=CON_STRING_1;EntityPath=first-binder-queue;'
...
Created queue client to connection string 'Endpoint=CON_STRING_2;EntityPath=second-binder-queue;'
...
```

When attempting to deploy the application Kubernetes however, the second binder doesn't work. I've moved the configuration to a ConfigMap:

```yaml
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  # same name as the application
  name: my-application
data:
  application.yaml: |-
    spring:
      application:
        name: my-application
      cloud:
        azure:
          servicebus:
            connection-string: CON_STRING_1
        stream:
          binders:
            second-binder:
              type: servicebus-queue
              default-candidate: false
              environment:
                spring:
                  cloud:
                    azure:
                      servicebus:
                        connection-string: CON_STRING_2
          bindings:
            first-destination:
              destination: first-binder-queue
            second-destination:
              destination: second-binder-queue
              binder: second-binder
      function:
        definition: my-function
```

I have the `spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config`, and the configuration is read from the config map, but the second binder is not being used, and the application attempts to connect to the second queue but in the ***first* binder**

```
com.microsoft.azure.servicebus.primitives.MessagingEntityNotFoundException: The messaging entity 'CON_STRING_1/second-binder-queue' could not be found. To know more visit https://aka.ms/sbResourceMgrExceptions.
```

1. The application does take the first connection string and other properties from the config map - the property source works as described in the [Spring-Kubernetes documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-kubernetes/1.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#configmap-propertysource).
2. If I deploy the application without the config map and keep the `application.yaml` in the jar, **the application works as expected**.

Any reason that only parts of the configuration will be used when switching to the `ConfigMap`?

Comment: Can you try to provide both connection-string properties as multi binder configuration environments? I see that you are providing one as a normal property and the second one using the multi-binder config. See this sample configuration for example:  https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/master/multi-binder-samples/kafka-multi-binder-jaas/src/main/resources/application.yml#L16

Comment: @sobychacko - The [Service-Bus Binder documentation](https://github.com/microsoft/spring-cloud-azure/blob/c856ec18357108062a4b249971e3e47caf0de497/spring-cloud-azure-samples/servicebus-queue-multibinders-sample/README.adoc) states that there is a limitation that default binder must be provided, so I must have a value there.

Comment: @apines could this be related to YAML syntax? I presume the `CON_STRING_1` contains some weird characters? Have you tried putting quotes around the connection-string value ? With the config-map, you are basically embedding a String value in the config-map YAML with the `|-` syntax. Also, have you verified that the app uses a service-account with permissions to read the ConfigMap ?